# How to install XFCE alongside with Gnome in Trusty

Tags: gnome, xfce

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed from mini.iso, install without any bloats. I was able to install gnome3 with gdm as greeter (LightDM always give me error message). The system run just fine, but I still like to use XCFE as my DE.

I've tried to install XFCE by running

> sudo apt-get install xfce4

but when I logout, I can't see the button to change session. What should I do?

I'm not using the command

> sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop

because what I read earlier, it will cause some trouble, along with the bloats later. I just want to install a DE, not any unneeded programs that are recommended.

Should I just reboot and see if everything will work, or am I really have to do something?

Comment: On the login screen by your name, there should be a gear that allows you to change the desktop you're going to log into next to the sign in button.

Comment: @Terrance , thanks, found it already. I thought it would be on the top panel along with the power button.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  Enjoy XFCE4, as that is what I run, I did a clean install too on my system from using the Minimal Install CD.  But it does run good when installed along side of Gnome Desktop.  I don't use the Gnome Desktop anymore.  It all boils down to preference.  =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo -i
apt-get install xfwm4 xfce4-panel xfce4-settings xfce4-session xfce4-terminal xfdesktop4 xfce4-taskmanager tango-icon-theme thunar
```

Or

```
sudo -i
apt-get install --no-install-recommends xubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Thanks, I've found what I searcg earlier. Just need to look around more. Sorry for causing trouble for you.